# Graph Dracula MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, graph

I have a lot to do with nodes and edges. I need to pull from a file/store, draw the graph, and allow interaction to apply filters or rendering styles. Graph Dracula seems perfect.

Unfortunately, I have only the basic understanding of HTML, JavaScript. I feel like AngularJS or the MVC pattern in general is what I need, but it's hard for me to get started. I'm having to learn too much all at once.

Can anybody refer me to a *platform* or recommend a basic set of html views & scripts that I could use as a launching pad for the MVC part?

Answer (score 0):

At my company we are using ASP.Net MVC to build web applications. Such applications are meant to be hosted inside an Microsoft Internet Information Services server or in the Azure cloud.

If you start in Visual Studio 2015 with File > New ... > Project and then select Templates -> Visual C# -> ASP.Net Web Application -> MVC , Visual Studio will scaffold a project that already works in principle and where you can add your content.
See http://www.asp.net/mvc for tutorials etc.

For data persistence, Microsoft Entity Framework works well with the MVC stack, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx for more.

Comment: Thanks Georg! I'll take a look at the MS patterns.

Comment: Good luck with your project :>